# Finding elements without id in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm adding several input fields to divs which I create dynamically. Currently, I give them a class based on the current increment. The result looks something like this (simplified):

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="c_1"/>
    <input type="text" class="c_2"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="c_1"/>
    <input type="text" class="c_2"/>
    <input type="text" class="c_3"/>
</div>
```

I'm mapping data to the elemets by doing something like:

```
$container.find('.c_' + id).val(value);
```

Where `$container` is the current container div in the iteration.

Since there can be up to 100 input elements in each div, I want to know if this is a good solution from a performance point of view. Would it be faster to target the elements by an HTML5 data attribute? Or should I try a different approach? Right now the mapping is pretty slow in older browsers.

Comment: if the `id` is incremental it would most likely be quicker to access them by index using `eq()`;

Comment: Searching for data attributes is rather slow, as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned using `eq()` on the container would be faster.

Comment: It depends mainly on how your script works.  If you're using `find()` every time you want to refer to an input then you'd probably be better off caching them in a suitable array and referring to that instead.  It's difficult to know the best way to go forward without knowing more.  Maybe an array with a function to get the input elements for you, and using the singleton approach may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that *all the children* of your container are the input elements you are interested in, you can access one element with

```
var input = $container.children[17];
```

which should be much faster than searching for a child with a specific class. You could even think about abandoning the class completely.

**jQuery:** If `$container` is a jQuery object - which it looks like it is -  you have to use something like

```
var input = $container.get().children[17];
```

to get access to the DOM Element directly

**JsPerf:** I have done a small [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/get-inputs-of-container) to compare JS `.children` to jQuery `find`, which shows that it actually is faster.